# node inaccessible via SSH postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14

inaccessible via SSH

```
[postgres@hq-pgsql-test01 ~]$ repmgr cluster crosscheck
INFO: connecting to database
 Name            | ID | 1 | 2
-----------------+----+---+---
 hq-pgsql-test01 | 1  | * | *
 hq-pgsql-test02 | 2  | ? | ?
WARNING: following problems detected:
  node 2 inaccessible via SSH
[postgres@hq-pgsql-test01 ~]$
```

how can i solve this problem node 2 inaccessible via SSH ???
and command in repmgr.conf

```
ssh_options='-q -o ConnectTimeout=10'
```

Comment: Are you able to access `hq-pgsql-test02` via `ssh` from this `hq-pgsql-test01` node upon which you ran the `repmgr` command? If not, why not? Is there something blocking Port 22 between these two nodes? Is `ssh` running on `node2`? Are ssh keys established and shared between these two systems? This is the kind of error that requires some troubleshooting.